# Nodejs Paypal Payouts SDK Malformed JSON Error

Tags: node.js, paypal

Hi I am currently trying to send a payout in sandbox mode using the payouts sdk in Nodejs after executing a paypal express payment.  The paypal express payment works properly, but for some reason I get an error when trying to perform the payout:

```
HttpError: {"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","message":"Invalid 
request - see details","debug_id":"219a050508b90","details": 
[{"field":"/","location":"body","issue":"MALFORMED_REQUEST_JSON"}],"links":[]}
```

Here is my code for initializing the payout:

```
try{
let environment = state.paypalMode === 'live' && process.env.VERSION !== 'testing' ? new payouts.core.LiveEnvironment(state.paypalClientId,state.paypalClientSecret)
        : new payouts.core.SandboxEnvironment(state.paypalClientId,state.paypalClientSecret);
    
    let client = new payouts.core.PayPalHttpClient(environment);
    let batchId = v4();

    let payoutObj = {
        sender_batch_header: {
            recipient_type: 'EMAIL',
            email_message: `${state.clientId} transaction occurred`,
            note: 'processing fee',
            sender_batch_id: batchId,
            email_subject: 'Processing Fee'
        },
        items: [{
            note: 'processing fee',
            amount: {
                currency: 'USD',
                value: processingFee
            },
            receiver: 'myemail@xyz.com',
            sender_item_id: (batchId + '_1')
        }]
    };

    let payoutsRequest = new payouts.payouts.PayoutsPostRequest();
    payoutsRequest.requestBody(JSON.stringify(payoutObj));

    let createPayouts = async() => {
        let payoutResponse = await client.execute(payoutsRequest);
        console.log(`payout response: ${JSON.stringify(payoutResponse)}`);
        console.log(`payouts create response: ${JSON.stringify(payoutResponse.result)}`);
        return payoutResponse.result;
    }

    let userPayoutResponse = await createPayouts();
}catch(e){
    console.log('handleProcessingFee error: ',e);
}
```

I've checked the example at https://github.com/paypal/Payouts-NodeJS-SDK and I still can't seem to figure out why it's not working in sandbox mode, any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the receiver [sandbox account](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts%2F) exists and has a confirmed email, https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessprofile/settings/email (if confirmation is needed, [read messages here](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fnotifications%2F))

If the problem persists, log your request body